# llvm/clang compile error with Memory exhausted

Tags: clang

I am trying to build the latest llvm/clang code on my ubuntu 14.04 vm, which has 2GB memory.

What I did is a normal configure/make procedure, without any parameters to these two commands.

at last, I have the following error:

> llvm[4]: Linking Debug+Asserts executable clang
>   /usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: Memory exhausted
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[4]: *** [/home/alex/Downloads/llvm_build/Debug+Asserts/bin/clang] Error 1
>   make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/alex/Downloads/llvm_build/tools/clang/tools/driver' 
>   make[3]: *** [driver/.makeall] Error 2 
>   make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/alex/Downloads/llvm_build/tools/clang/tools'
>   make[2]: *** [all] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/alex/Downloads/llvm_build/tools/clang' 
>   make[1]: *** [clang/.makeall] Error 2 
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/alex/Downloads/llvm_build/tools'
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: how much swap space have you made available to the kernel?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to do one of the following:

1. Add more RAM to your VM, or
2. Use gold instead of ld as a linker, or
3. Build Release(-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release), not Debug build

Comment: One way to use gold is to run this command before building clang: `sudo ln -s \`which gold\` /usr/local/bin/ld`

Comment: [LLVM docs](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) suggest an alternative way: "to link LLVM with the Gold linker, cmake can be invoked with `-DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold`"

Comment: I've found that lld works just as well/even better than gold.

Answer (score 14):

Another consideration: If you have Make running parallel jobs (e.g., `make -j8`), the concurrently executing jobs may require too much memory.

Comment: This helped me immensely. How is memory allocated when running make? If all but one thread has completed compilation, doesn't the final thread get the all available physical memory?

Comment: I had set up a 9 GB swap file for building this and Firefox on a Pi 3B (1 GB physical RAM) but several times now it fails with "mmap: failed to allocate 1071003436 bytes for output file".  It's trying to allocate 1 GB as a file buffer and swap isn't good enough.  I'm using Gold and -J 1.  Never saw this before, I guess it's a show-stopper.

Comment: See https://www.llvm.org/docs/CMake.html which lists things you can turn off by editing your CMakeCache.txt.  I'm trying CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release and CLANG_DEFAULT_LINKER:STRING=gold and LLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD:STRING=ARM.

Comment: Yup, OK,those 3 things in CMakeCache.txt made the difference.  It built with 1 GB of actual RAM.  Took about 24 hours but that's expected.

Comment: You may also want to look at LLVM's [`LLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS`](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#llvm-specific-variables) cmake option to limit the number of parallel link jobs if you are able to use a `ninja` build...